# Xamarin Forms get cursor position in editor control

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I get the cursor position inside Editor control?

Ive been looking for an answer but the best I could find was the Cursor class, but that doesnt seem to exist in xamarin.

Comment: do you mean the cursor position in an Entry or Editor control?

Comment: @Jason My bad, I meant Editor control, Updating question

Comment: Entry has a CursorPosition property, Editor does not.  https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5093

Comment: Sounds like in the meantime [a custom renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) would be needed.

Comment: thanks, I'll check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could custom a Editor,and use [custom renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) to get the `SelectionPosition` of the `EditText`.

custom a **FormEditor** in your fomrs project:

```
public class FormEditor:Editor
{
    public int SelectionPosition;

    public EventHandler SelectChanageEvent { get; set; }
}
```

create **AndroidEditor** in your Android project:

```
class AndroidEditor : EditorRenderer, EditTextSelectChange
{
    private Context mContext;

    public AndroidEditor(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void Change(int lastPos, int curPos)
    {

        ((FormEditor)Element).SelectionPosition = curPos;
        ((FormEditor)Element).SelectChanageEvent.Invoke(this, null);
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        MyEditText myEditText = new MyEditText(mContext);
        myEditText.SetEditTextSelectChange(this);
        SetNativeControl(myEditText);

    }
}
```

custom **MyEditText** in your Android project:

```
public class MyEditText : FormsEditText
{

    private int mLastPos = 0;
    private int mCurPos = 0;
    private EditTextSelectChange editTextSelectChange;

    public void SetEditTextSelectChange(EditTextSelectChange editTextSelectChange)
    {
        this.editTextSelectChange = editTextSelectChange;
    }
    public MyEditText(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }


    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd)
    {
        base.OnSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);
        if (editTextSelectChange != null)
        {
            mCurPos = selEnd;
            editTextSelectChange.Change(mLastPos, mCurPos);
            mLastPos = mCurPos;
        }
    }
    public interface EditTextSelectChange
    {
        void Change(int lastPos, int curPos);
    }
}
```

then use in your page.xaml:

```
 <local:FormEditor x:Name="editor" Placeholder="Hello"></local:FormEditor>
```

in your page.xaml.cs:

```
public YourPage()
  {
        InitializeComponent();
        editor.SelectChanageEvent += SelectEvent;
  }

  
  private void SelectEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     // you could get the Curson Position by editor.SelectionPosition
     Console.WriteLine("curPos = {0}", editor.SelectionPosition);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me with android. Maybe you have an implementation for ios?